# Car Stalls After Running AC Heating System

Tags: ac, cel, diagnostics, obd

My 2011 Nissan Rogue is stalling out on me.  The first time this happened was after going over a speed bump in heavy snow - I sent it to a garage and they told me that there were "No OBD Codes To Scan" and that I would need to take it to a dealership.

After doing some research into what that would take and how much they'd take it for, I decided to do some more research into the issue - near as I can tell, the car seems to only stall out when the AC unit is running. It stalls after a certain amount of time and then will not run at all.  When it stalls, the Battery, Oil, Break, and Check Engine lights come on.

As the garage said, there are no OBD codes, but when I stick my reader in it the "CAT" "EVAP" "O25" and "EGR" indicators flash and the reader shows a yellow warning light.

I also tried moving it a little, and heard a scraping sound - looking underneath the car, it looks like some kind of cover has come loose.

Pictured below is the dashboard lights, the OBD "Code", and the piece on the bottom that has come loose.

[image: Car Dashboard Indicator Lights With Battery, Oil, Break, and Engine lights on]
[image: OBD2 Reader with no codes, CAT, EVAP, O2S and EGR indicators on, yellow light on]
[image: Part hanging loose under car - cover for some pipe?]

Comment: The flashing indicators and yellow light on your OBDII reader means these have not passed the Drive Cycle for the vehicle. It is most likely this way because the system was reset as when clearing codes. Basically, it means nothing, other than completing the drive cycle.

Comment: Or it could mean that all battery voltage was lost when going over a bump. If the modules lose voltage the drive cycles need to reset. I would be looking at the battery to see if it's properly mounted. Also check and clean both ends of all cables coming from the battery. Also find all body to engine ground straps and check and clean them. I suspect that the battery and or alternator current is being disconnected when you hit a bump. Or the AC compressor is locking up.

Comment: @Jupiter This would make sense, except that I tested it when standing still and it would eventually stall out after about 14 minutes with the AC running - does this indicate the AC Compressor is likely the issue, or would it still potentially be a battery issue?

Comment: I'm leaning toward the AC compressor freezing up. If you find a fuse that activates the compressor clutch, you can pull that fuse so the clutch doesn't engage. If the problem goes away, you solved it. Or you can open the hood and watch the AC pulley and see if it locks while you watch. Keep your face away from belt just in case it breaks.